# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. Ionic - Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic4

I am currently struggling with with the Error:

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

It comes up based on this logic:

```
let aNewList = [];
aNewList = this.Listen.filter( function(item) { return item !== ID });
```

Listen is returned by the **setup()** function. There it is defined like:

`const = ref(null);` - Containing an Array of Objects

I know for sure that **this.Listen** is filled.
But the error won't let me start my application when using functions like **.filter** etc.

Does anyone know How I can suppress this error?

I am using Ionic 4 with Vue.js.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code for how `this.Listen` gets assigned to?

Comment: Try the optional chaining `aNewList = this.Listen?.filter`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim In this case `| undefined` will propagate to aNewList.

Comment: @CertainPerformance List is returned by the setup() function. There it is defined like: const = ref(null); - Containing an Array of Objects

Comment: Please put all the relevant code into the question.

Comment: @LukasMetzger Please, update the question with relevant code. It's unclear how `this.Listen` and a ref are related. Refs are supposed to be accessed through `value`, it's possible that `filter` property really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned, it's giving you a notice that `Listen` could be null, so your code could be trying to run `undefined.filter()` which is not going to work.

The question remains, what would you like to happen, and I'm assuming the answer is return an empty array, so you could do any of these:

```js
// use optional chaining and return [] instead of undefined
let aNewList = this.Listen?.filter( function(item) { return item !== ID }) || [];

// filter on empty array
let aNewList = (this.Listen || []).filter( function(item) { return item !== ID });


// handle in try..catch but this might not suppress the actual eslint notice, but would handle the exception even when optional chaining is not available.
let aNewList = []
try(){
  aNewList = this.Listen.filter( function(item) { return item !== ID });
} catch () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables and properties that are potentially `null` are naturally handled with type safeguards:

if (this.Listen) {
// null is excluded from Listen type
}

Otherwise non-null assertion can be used:

```
aNewList = this.Listen!.filter(...);
```

In a case where a value is initialized shortly after and is guaranteed to be not null or undefined in all places where it's used, non-null assertion can be done on variable or property declaration:

```
...
Listen: null!,
...
```